# Printing all objects from a class

Tags: python, class, printing

I currently have a class that turns my list of lists into a list of objects, where every object has a certain amount of stuff from the constructor. Lets say they have names, and some random numbers.

What I would like to do is print all of these objects simultaneously, where each object is one line. How would I go about doing this, I tried making a **Str** function, but it still returns  ""

Okay, I have a class which has 10 objects, these have the attributes self.planet, self.distance, self.distsquared, self.radius, self.diamater where distance/distsquared/radius/diamater are all integers and I have a function which is supposed to print all of the planets after their distance, with the furthest distance highest. But when I try to make a function return "" % (self.planet, self.distance, self.distsquared, self.radius self.diameter) it still only prints  I want every object to be printed
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add more details, perhaps? Include your code, give examples of expected output / current output?

Comment: Okay, I have a class which has 10 objects, these have the attributes self.planet, self.distance, self.distsquared, self.radius, self.diamater where distance/distsquared/radius/diamater are all integers and I have a function which is supposed to print all of the planets after their distance, with the furthest distance highest. But when I try to make a function 
return "<planet:%s distance:%s distsquared:%s radius:%s radius:%sdiameter>" % (self.planet, self.distance, self.distsquared, self.radius self.diameter) it still only prints <class '__main__.Planets'>

I want every object to be printed

Comment: In your answer (edit it) not in comments, yes? Easier to read, for others to reply to, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a list of objects, you can print them neatly using:

```
print("\n".join(str(x) for x in object_list))
```

The class should have the function to make each object into a string as follows:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Attr1: {0.attr1}, Attr2: {0.attr2}, ...".format(self)
```

Comment: Or: `return 'Attr1: {0.attr1} Attr2: {0.attr2}'.format(self)` or similar to make the most of formatting

Comment: Oh I like that, thanks